# Verbo importare con soggetto animato?

Tags: grammar

Premetto che intendo "importare" con il significato di "avere importanza".
Trovo bizzarro (forse è solo un mio problema) usare il verbo "importare" in certi contesti riferendosi ad una persona.
Esempio:

1) Tu in questa azienda non importi niente

2) Tu qui non importi tanto, anzi sei quasi d'intralcio

Volendo usare un soggetto inanimato invece il tutto mi risulta più orecchiabile:

3) Questo discorso in questo momento importa davvero poco

4) Questa tua opinione qui non importa niente

Per non sbagliare, io uso sempre il verbo "contare" e noterete che in tutte e quattro le frasi suona bene.

Domanda:  c'è una spiegazione logica e grammaticale a questa mia sensazione oppure è solo un mio problema? Ma soprattutto le frasi da me scritte sono tutte corrette?

Comment: E quale sarebbe la domanda?

Comment: Nakamura, potresti per favore spiegare che tipo di risposte ti aspetti? Altrimenti temo di doverlo chiudere come "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Volevo sapere se c'è una spiegazione logica  e grammaticale a questa mia sensazione e le se le frasi in questione sono corrette.

Comment: «Tu in questa azienda non importi niente» «Infatti, mi occupo solo di esportazioni». Scherzi a parte, forse un motivo per cui quelle frasi ti suonano strane è che se il soggetto è animato è più facile l'equivoco con l'altro senso di “importare”.

Comment: La spiegazione non è nella grammatica o nella logica, bensì nella semantica. Questo significa che sebbene due o più parole, espressioni, siano sinonimi oppure siano usate nelle definizioni rispettive definizioni, non è detto che possano essere intercambiabili. Nel caso proposto, secondo me va bene dire «In questa azienda hai importanza / sei importante» o «Conti molto».